# Get-MailboxFolderPermission - foreach loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I am trying to output all AD users calendar and contact permissions. I have tried adding an `-or` operator but as per the error screenshot it does not work. I am not sure if `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` can take more than one parameter.

This script does not run

```
$OU = OrganizationalUnit "OU=users,OU=test.com,OU=PIPE,OU=Hosting,DC=options,DC=com"

Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU -Filter * |
    select -Expand alias |
    Where-Object {Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $($_ + ':\Calendar') -or $($_ + ':\Contacts')} |
    select Identity, FolderName, User, @{name="AccessRights";expression={[string]::Join(",",@($_.accessrights))}}, IsValid |
    Sort-Object Identity |
    Export-Csv C:\temp\calendarpemstest2.csv
```

[image]

This script runs fine just getting calendar permissions

```
$OU = OrganizationalUnit "OU=users,OU=test.com,OU=PIPE,OU=Hosting,DC=options,DC=com"

Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU -Filter * |
    select -Expand alias |
    ForEach-Object {Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $($_ + ':\Calendar')} |
    select Identity, FolderName, User, @{name="AccessRights";expression={[string]::Join(",",@($_.accessrights)) }}, IsValid |
    Sort-Object Identity |
    Export-Csv C:\temp\calendarpemstest2.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell tries to parse the `-or` parameter for `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`, but [Get-MailboxFolderPermission](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335061(v=exchg.160).aspx) does not have an `-or` parameter.

One way to work around this problem is to pipe the same aliases object twice (once for `Calendar` and once for `Contacts`).

```
$OU=OrganizationalUnit "OU=users,OU=test.com,OU=PIPE,OU=Hosting,DC=options,DC=com"
$aliases = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU -filter *  | select -expand alias
$calendarPermissions = $aliases | ForEach-Object { Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity $($_ + ':\Calendar' ) } 
$contactsPermissions = $aliases | ForEach-Object { Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity $($_ + ':\Contacts' ) }

# now merge both permissions and pipe to the rest of the code
$calendarPermissions + $contactsPermissions |
Select Identity, FolderName, User, @{name="AccessRights";expression={ [string]::join(",",@($_.accessrights)) }}, IsValid |
Sort-Object identity |
Export-Csv C:\temp\calendarpemstest2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried running the code all at once, excluding the comment and received the following error message: 

- **Note** It did produce an output which seems to be correct

`Export-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "OU=users,OU=test.com,OU=PIPE,OU=Hosting,DC=options,DC=com" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."
At line:4 char:64
+ Export-Csv C:\temp\calendarpemstest2.csv$OU=OrganizationalUnit "OU=users ...`

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with the way you copied the code. I see the first line appended at the end of last line. You can copy the whole thing and paste it to a Powershell window, including the comment. Comment won’t make a difference.If you are not familiar with piping, the last four lines is a single statement and should be executed altogether.