# Combine multiple foreach results into a single report

Tags: powershell

```
$results = foreach ($Mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited))
{
    get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "$($Mailbox.Name):\Calendar" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object {$_.User -notlike "Default" -and
                      $_.User -notlike "Anonymous" -and
                      $_.AccessRights -notlike "None" -and
                      $_.AccessRights } |
        Select @{N="Mailbox";E={$Mailbox.SamAccountName}}, FolderName, User, AccessRights
}
$results
```

I am still learning powershell (only 1 full year of experience).  I'm using this code to report on calendar permissions for all end user mailboxes in our environment.  The code works well but it only reports on the Calendar object.  I need to run three separate reports to get the Calendar, Contacts, and Inbox permissions.

I have tried creating an array but it throws multiple values all on one line. (Some end users have more than one person with access to their Calendar/Contacts/Inbox.  Does anyone have a good idea of how to combine these results?

thanks

[Here is an example of what results I would like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K83P.jpg)

Comment: First answer would be run another loop to check each mailbox for each folder. Have you tried something like that? I am also fuzzy one what you want the output to look like. Do you have a facsimile you could show so answers can get the right output the first time?

Comment: I believe you mean `-notmatch` or `-ne` in those comparisons.  `like` is for wildcards (which you're not using any of)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 `-notcontains` would also help here. I guess I would not suggest using `-notmatch` for the same reason you suggest not using `-notlike` that and the regex support can be surprising sometimes.

Comment: Again, the script does work (but for only one object at a time (in this instance "\Calendar".

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516483/get-mailboxfolderpermission-foreach-loop

Comment: Mustafa, thanks!  That did it... I was unaware of using the merge concept.  I had to keep it in the Foreach() format to pull the Mailbox name but it definitely did the trick.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating Mailboxes only once with an additional

`ForEach ($Folder in 'Contents','Calendar','Inbox')`

Should be more efficient:

```
#Date

$date = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)

#Pull Permissions

$Permissions = ForEach ($Mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited )) { 
    ForEach ($Folder in 'Contents','Calendar','Inbox'){
        Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "$($Mailbox.Name):\$($Folder)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
          Where-Object {$_.User -notlike "Default" -and $_.User -notlike "Anonymous" -and $_.AccessRights -notlike "None" -and $_.AccessRights } | 
            Select @{N="Mailbox";E={$Mailbox.SamAccountName}}, 
                   @{N="Folder";E={$_.FolderName}}, 
                   @{N="User With Access";E={$_.User}}, 
                   @{N="Access";E={$_.AccessRights}}
    }
}

#Export to Desktop

$Permissions | Sort User | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ExchangePermissions-$Date.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried, only 1200 results to my 1800 from 2 days ago.  Then I realized "Contacts" is spelled wrong in your script.  Otherwise I think it works will.  I also decided to pull in the Office and Title for the mailbox.  I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Date

$date = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)

#Pull Permissions

$Permissions = ForEach ($Mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited )) {
    $userInfo = get-user $Mailbox.name | select Title 
    ForEach ($Folder in 'Contacts','Calendar','Inbox'){
        Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "$($Mailbox.Name):\$($Folder)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
          Where-Object {$_.User -notlike "Default" -and $_.User -notlike "Anonymous" -and $_.AccessRights -notlike "None" -and $_.AccessRights } | 
            Select @{N="Mailbox";E={$Mailbox.SamAccountName}},
                   @{N="Office";E={$Mailbox.Office}},
                   @{N="Title";E={$userInfo.Title}},
                   @{N="Folder";E={$_.FolderName}}, 
                   @{N="User With Access";E={$_.User}}, 
                   @{N="Access";E={$_.AccessRights}}
    }
}

#Export to Desktop

$Permissions | Sort User | Export-Csv 
"$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ExchangePermissions-$Date.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```